# Setting custom data attribute with jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console.log, custom-data-attribute

I just can't wrap my head around this. I tried to add a data-diff attribute to some elements. Seems to work, yet no such attribute appears in the html. No big deal I thought, opened developer tools and my trail of thought went like this:

Lets set this attribute again:

```
console: $(obj).data('diff','10');

output: [div.cont]
```

Good, let's check the attribute then:

```
console: $(obj).data('diff')

output: "10"
```

Great, but still it doesn't appear in HTML, let's check this:

```
console: $(obj)[0]

output: 

    <div class="cont" data-month="8" data-round="1">
        (Tom) 8
        <div class="secCol">AUG</div>
    </div>
```

Hmm, indeed there is no data-diff, maybe if I try this:

```
console: $(obj)[0].data('diff','10')

output: Uncaught TypeError: $(...)[0].data is not a function(…)
```

I guess it has something to do with DOM elements vs jQuery objects (already read [this](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-pull-a-native-dom-element-from-a-jquery-object/)) but I don't know what else to try. My code is this:

```
$('.cont[data-round="'+round+'"]').each(function(i, obj) {
    var month = $(obj).data('month');
     var diff = Math.abs(myMonth-month);
     $(obj).data('diff', diff);//Here is the problem
});
```

Comment: `$(obj)[0]` gives you the HTML element, `.data()` is a jQuery function. 
Workaround: `$($(obj)[0]).data('diff')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is normal behaviour.

The setter of jQuery's `data()` method *only* updates the object that jQuery stores in memory which holds all `data-*` attributes within the DOM. So long as you only use `data()` to get and to set the values, this is not a problem. In fact it's quicker.

To actually have the `data-*` attribute appear in the DOM you need to use `attr()` however it will be less efficient. For example:

```
$(obj).attr('data-diff', diff);
```

You can select the element by it's `data-*` attribute in the DOM as you would any other attribute:

```
var $foo = $('.foo[data-bar="fizz"]')
```

Alternatively, if you want to select an element by it's in-memory data attribute (as you would when using `data()` to set attributes), use `filter()`:

```
var $foo = $('.foo').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('bar') === 'fizz';
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery `.data()` method simply does not do that. It will **read** `data-foo` attributes from DOM elements, but it never adds them.

Unless you're mixing jQuery with some other framework that expects to find those attributes (which might include some CSS I suppose), there's really not much point in putting the attributes in the DOM.

Comment: How can I select elements by data-diff = 10 (for example) then? `$('.cont[data-diff="10"]')` returns nothing.

Comment: @TheodoreK. yes, if you're interested in using the data attributes as ways of addressing elements in the DOM, then you'd need to create the attributes. Personally I would do it with a class, but that's just me. In any case, it was a jQuery design decision some years ago not to do that.